# PhoneGap: Update Files (.html) for further use offline

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I want to have an app, that provides only simple information in an table. 
I use PhoneGap. I got my information right now and I can write them in the HTML file.
But there will be some changes, do I have to wait with the publish, or is it possible to get the new `infos.html` file from my server with an click on a refresh button and store it local, so the user still can get it w/out internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

You can't replace the local files. What you *can* do is build your interfaces dynamically using Javascript and use AJAX to download the HTML for them. You can store it locally for offline access using `window.localStorage`.